# How to read input in a html page with javascript without focus in one field

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I want to ask how can someone read keystrokes while in a html page without having focus in a particular field. Is there some event that i can hook a method that reads input?

Thanks in advance.

PS. We use JQuery if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `document.onkeypress` (or the siblings `onkeydown` and `onkeyup`):

```
document.onkeypress = function (event) { ... };
```

[jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Events) offers for these events, e.g.,

```
$(document).keypress (function (event) { ... });
```

This will catch *all* key press events on your site. Inside the function you can get the numeric code of the pressed key with `event.keyCode`. Be aware, that there are some browser incompatibilities, especially with the `keypress` event. See [developer.mozilla.com](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.keyCode) for how FF handles it.

Cheers,