# Can I access a URL by typing a code instead of having to click an <a> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Imagine I have this:

```
<li><a href="{{ route('admin') }}">Admin Panel</a></li>
```

Is there a way to remove this and make it so that if a user types "admin" to be sent to that page using JavaScript + jQuery?

I've seen web sites that execute some code if you type a certain phrase so I've been wondering if I could implement something similar.

Comment: Have a look at this; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript

Comment: This could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100251/how-to-read-input-in-a-html-page-with-javascript-without-focus-in-one-field

Comment: Thanks fellas, this seems to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: where do you type the string "admin"?

Comment: Not in any specific input field, just when you're on the main page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```js
    function gotoPage(input){
      if (input.value == "admin") {
        window.open('http://www.google.com');
      }
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" value="" onkeyup="gotoPage(this)">
```